# ObjectStateManager Error at CodeFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

Hi i am working on a MVC project with EF CodeFirst and when i try to Remove from db it gives me this error message

**Class**

```
    public class PurchaseOrders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double tl { get; set; }
    public double btc { get; set; }
    public double total { get; set; }
    public Users user { get; set; }
    public Rates rate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

**Error :**

```
db.PurchaseOrders.Remove(pOrder);
```

[image: This is How is My Exception Looking]

Comment: It looks like you did not fetch this object from database before deletion attempt

Comment: but i did it. i select all items as list and try to delete with in a foreach loop

Comment: Show whole code, not just chunk image.

Comment: İnvoke Method : http://codepad.org/jqs2j3DN ---
 Wrong Code Block : ---http://codepad.org/WBXqu8Oq